# How can I set an IPsec ID using the Windows 8 built-in VPN client?

Tags: networking, windows-8, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, ipsec

I'm trying to connect to a VPN using the built in Windows 8 VPN client. The VPN uses L2TP/IPsec and a pre-shared key. I can see it's connecting to the VPN but not making it through authentication. I get the following error:

> Error: 789 "The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer encountered a processing error during initial negotiations with the remote computer"

I then noticed I didn't set the IPsec ID, or 'Group Authentication -  Name' as it appears in the Cisco VPN client. I'd like to avoid the Cisco VPN client as it feels clunky on a tablet.

How can I set an IPsec ID using the Windows 8 built-in VPN client?